# Can the Google HTTP(S) Global Load Balancer failover to different types of backends?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, google-cloud-run

The HTTP(S) Global LB has ["Automatic failover to healthy backends"](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#failover).

But can it failover to different backend *types*?

For example, the LB might direct all traffic to a GCE Instance Group.  (There would be no distinct path routing rules.)

But if the Instance Group backend  fails its healthcheck, the LB would  send traffic to a Serverless Network Endpoint Group to direct all traffic to a Cloud Function.

Can that be done?

Comment: You need to be specific in how you are configuring everything including path routing rules. Read this link to help understand what is supported. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs

Comment: Thank you. There would be no distinct path routing rules. All traffic would go to the  Instance Group, but if that fails, all traffic would go to the Cloud Function

Comment: In that case, yes as documented in the link in my comment.

Comment: Thank  you. I set up the serverless NEG as described there. But I don't see that it describes how to failover between two different backend services -- particularly as distinct paths seem to be requires for setting up multiple backend services, and in this case we do not want distinct paths.

Comment: Details on your configuration are required to help you. Since you already configured this, why did you not start with a problem statement seeking a solution?

Comment: I thought that I had. What further details of configuration would you suggest?

Comment: Currently the docs linked above say "[...] health checks are not supported for backend services", so I'm inclined to think the failover features are not working today. However if a NEG is misconfigured (e.g. underlying app deleted), I'm guessing the traffic goes to another NEG in the same backend.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google In the example that I gave, the primary backend service is a GCE Managed Instance Group, where healthchecks are supported. Given that, would we get the failover that I am describing?

Comment: @AhmetB-Google  You said "I'm guessing the traffic goes to another NEG in the same backend." I am asking about failover from one type of service (GCE VM) to another (Cloud Function). So, failover within a single backend would not satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation in serverless NEGs, since you cannot mix serverless NEGs with other types of NEGs (zonal or internet NEGs) in the same backend service. As you mentioned in the original post, I presume Joshua wants a failover. I wonder if there are uses people want for mixing NEG types -- such as migrating to (or from) GCE Instance Group to Cloud Functions.

[Serverless NEG Concepts - Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts#backend-service-limitations)

Comment: Thank you. Right, we can't mix these in a single backend /backend service. But can we have two backend services, one GCE and one Cloud Functions, or one GKE  and one Cloud Run, and then  set up a failover between them?

Comment: Did you find a way to have two backend services and setup a failover between them (if all of the backends in backend service `x` are not healthy, route the request to backend service `y`)?